# React cannot choose from select multiple form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, reactjs, coffeescript

So I'm making a `select multiple` form in React.js, yet every time options are generated, I cannot select the options. If I click on an option, it is instantly unhighlighted and not selected.

```
React.DOM.div({
  className: 'form-group'
}, React.DOM.select({
     multiple: true,
     name: 'team_players',
     value: this.state.team_players,
     onChange: this.handleArrayChange
}, React.DOM.option({
     value: '',
     disabled: true
}, 'Select Players'), (function() {
    var i, len, ref, results;
    ref = this.state.players;
    results = [];
    for (i = 0, len = ref.length; i < len; i++) {
       player = ref[i];
       results.push(React.DOM.option({
       key: player.id,
       value: player.detail.inputs["NAME"]
    }, player.detail.inputs["NAME"]));
 }
 return results;
}).call(this)));
```

*Please note that this is the js version generated through js2.coffee from my coffeescript version which goes as such: *

```
React.DOM.div
className: 'form-group'
React.DOM.select
  multiple: true
  name: 'team_players'
  value: @state.team_players
  onChange: @handleArrayChange
  React.DOM.option
    value: ''
    disabled: true
    'Select Players'
    for player in @state.players
      React.DOM.option
      key: player.id
      value: player.detail.inputs["NAME"]
      player.detail.inputs["NAME"]
```

My handleArrayChange function goes as such:

```
({
handleArrayChange: function(e) {
  var i, len, name, obj, option, options, team_array;
  options = e.target.options;
  name = e.target.name;
  team_array = [];
  for (i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; i++) {
    option = options[i];
    team_array.push(option);
  }
  return this.setState((
    obj = {},
    obj["" + name] = team_array,
    obj
  ));
}
});
```

and in its coffescript form:

```
handleArraychange: (e) ->
  options = e.target.options
  name = e.target.name
  team_array = []
  for option in options 
    team_array.push option
  @setState "#{name}": team_array
```

Why does this form not handle my inputs properly?

Comment: The `disabled: true` should only disable that specific option, the issue is that the non disabled options, when selected, are immediately deselected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the `team_array` state as an array of *option HTML elements*, not an array of strings. Try this instead:

```
handleArraychange: (e) ->
  options = e.target.options
  name = e.target.name
  team_array = []
  for option in options 
    team_array.push option.value
  @setState "#{name}": team_array
```